# ChartJs tooltip height option doesn't work

Tags: chart.js

im using `ChartJs` for displaying graph, and i try to costumize tooltip height using `height` on `options` based on `ChartJs` documentation.

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html

but it doesnt work.
this is my `option` on my Chart.

```
options {
    tooltips: {
        mode: 'point',
        intersect: true,
        xPadding: 10,
        yPadding: 10,
        bodySpacing: 4,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        borderColor: '#eff6ff',
        borderWidth: 2,
        height: 10,
        titleFontColor: '#1fb7c7',
        bodyFontColor: '#333333'
    }
}
```

[image: myCurrentTooltip]
i need to make the tooltip like this way.

[image: tooltipWannaBe]

Answer (score 0):

There is no configuration naming 'height' for tooltips, so it will not work.

```
tooltips: {
    height:10
}
```

Instead, you can use **bodyFontSize**, the height of the tooltip will be altered based on the value you assign to it.

```
tooltips: {
   bodyFontSize:15
}
```

And use **position** and **mode** options to change the postion of the tooltips.

Comment: it is? i need to resize the height of tooltip to make the height fix.

Comment: Yes you can resize as you want, I see no other option other than bodyFontSize.

Comment: edit: i add the example picture on my question. is it possible to make it like that?